# CoreData Delete hangs in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-data

I am developing an App for The iPhone (iOS5 and above) using XCode 4.4.1 and Core Data.

I have a number of entities which I can view and delete using NSTableViewControllers ( separate controllers, but with similar code )

One of the entities ( ExpenseItem )  is deleting without any problem, but the deleting the other entities causes the execution to be blocked.

The debug Navigator shows a thread symbol and the word 'Running', but I have to press the Stop button to get back into the edtor.

I am not creating any threads, so I am at a loss after a number of hours trying everything I can think of !

Here is some code I wrote to debug the problem - it saves the ExpenseItem Object but hangs on the Account Object. If I comment out the ExpenseAccount save, the Account save still hangs, but vice versa still works.

```
// deleteObject  ** why does this hang ???

-(void)deleteObjectX {                                                                  

    NSNumber *ExpenseKey    = [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];            // test data
    NSString *AccountCode  = @"Cash";

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    NSManagedObject* thisExpenseItemObject = [self getExpenseItemObject:ExpenseKey];  //   ExpenseItem
    NSManagedObject* thisAccountObject = [self getAccountObject:AccountCode];         // Account

   // if the next 3 lines are commented out it still hangs on the last line

  [managedObjectContext deleteObject:thisExpenseItemObject];         // OK
  BOOL result = [thisExpenseItemObject isDeleted];                   // result is YES
  [managedObjectContext save:nil];                                   // works 

  [managedObjectContext deleteObject:thisAccountObject];             // OK
  result = [thisAccountObject isDeleted];                            // result is YES
  [managedObjectContext save:nil];                                   // ***Hangs Here ! ***
```

}

I will be grateful for any suggestions !

Thanks, Ross

Comment: Does an Account have any relationships?  If so, what are their delete rules?  (If you pause execution during the hang, what does the stack look like?)

Comment: There are no relationships and no rules - just the entities.

Comment: Remove the upper managed object context save line & try again. Hope it should work for you to delete both object.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that.  My reply above should have read : There are no relationships and no rules - just the entities. When I pause execution during the hang ( thanks - I didn't know I could do that ! ) I get the following stack in the Debug Navigator : Thread 1; ) sqlite3BtreeOpen; 11-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]; 12 -[XeXDataModel deleteObjectX]; 13- [XeXInfoViewController deleteAllocation]; 14-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]; 32 UIApplicationMain;33 main; 34 start;  There is also a Thread 2 and a Thread 4 WebThread which appear to be system generated.

Comment: Looking at the Debug stack again, if I run and pause repeatedly it comes up with a different message at the top each time, including a variety of sqlite ones. It seems to be in a loop - it's using 100% of one of my CPU cores.